# embed .swf inline into html using base64 encoding

Tags: html, flash, base64

**try to do:** embed .swf into html inline using base64 encoding

i read a post somewhere saying this is no longer possible with flash 10+
any hacks or definitive answer?

```
'data:application/x-shockwave-flash;base64,Q1dTChQHAAB4(cut)9ktAW5/4BvdnQmw=='
```

does not work anymore

Answer (score -1):

Why, I think if you do that on `<object>` tag it should work, not sure why would it depend on Player's version, I'd imagine that the SWF is loaded by the browser, not the player.